# accessing the mapped network drives using mingw shell

Tags: windows, shell, network-drive, mingw

How to access the mapped network drives from the mingw shell? When I try

`cd y:` or `cd /y` or `y:`

All I get is `No such file or directory` or `sh.exe y:: command not found`.

I am able to access the same mapped Y: drive using `cmd`. I would like to know how to do the same using mingw shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `cd /y/` to solve your problem

Comment: Care to explain why it works this way?

Comment: I'm able to access the drive from mingw shell if the drive is actually connected. That is, if I double click and open the drive in Windows Explorer and then use Mingw to `cd` into it, then it works.

Comment: Just FYI, if you're trying to access installed Windows Subsystem for Linux distributions, which are exposed as if they were network shares, you'll need to escape the `$` character. So do `cd //wsl\$/Ubuntu/home/${USER}`, for example, to access your WSL home directory (assuming Ubuntu and the same username). Microsoft uses a dollar sign in the name of this "fake" network share to avoid conflicts with existing networks, since an actual machine name can’t have a dollar sign in it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this format in MINGW64 shell (Bash for windows)

$ cd //IP_Address_of_remote_drive/Path/To/The/Folder/

Answer (score 3):

I find I have to use the mount command first.  If I have a USB stick on drive E: then in the mingw shell:

```
mount e: /e
```

Only then can I run `cd /e/`.  You can run `mount` without parameters to list all the currently known file systems.  `umount /e` will remove the link between E: and /e/.

Comment: I have a "mapped network drive" as "S:" but when I run `$ mount S: /s` in MingW64 (git back) I get `mount: warning - /s does not exist.`

Comment: It seems that my problem was that I was running git bash in elevated mode (set "Run as administrator"), and evidently the admin user didn't have an authenticated session with the file server or something like that.